# point cloud generated from the images taken by the stereo rig in opencv

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d, point-cloud-library, disparity-mapping

I can view the point clouds that are given with the Point Cloud Library. But, the problem is I cannot view my point cloud which I have generated from my stereo rig images.
The images are of resolution 640x480 pixels.

But, the number of points in the point cloud varies for every pair of images(i.e., instead of having 307200 points it has less number of points like 194261, 190472, etc.).

Why do I don't get a 307200 points in the point cloud?

And how should I view such a point cloud using Point Cloud Library?

Comment: for future reference: point-cloud-library is the correct tag, pcl is for printer command language

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this example [Example1](http://blog.martinperis.com/2012/01/3d-reconstruction-with-opencv-and-point.html) and [Example2](http://www.pcl-users.org/saving-data-td4019514.html). It also depends on the kind of sensor you are using for image acquisition.